# Remove hover/click states of buttons

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

How can I override the hover and click states of a jQuery Mobile button?

I have a button like this:

```
<a class="aButton" href='#' data-role="button" data-icon="check">My Button</a>
```

If I use the following CSS override, it still highlights the button if I hold on it or click it, I don't want any of those. I just can't figure out what is causing the highlighting, I've tried everything (it's a button style B, but thought I'd put all the other classes in just in case)!

```
.ui-btn, a, .aButton, .ui-btn-a, .ui-btn-b, .ui-btn-c, .ui-btn-d, .ui-btn-e, .ui-btn-down-a, .ui-btn-down-b, .ui-btn-down-c, .ui-btn-down-d, .ui-btn-down-e, .ui-btn-hover-a, .ui-btn-hover-b, .ui-btn-hover-c, .ui-btn-hover-d, .ui-btn-hover-e {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#DDDDDD, #CCCCCC) repeat scroll 0 0 #030303 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised I was doing something stupid. The background wasn't being applied at all because I was using **-moz**-linear-gradient on my Android phone when it should be **-webkit**-linear-gradient... wooops.

Answer (score 1):

use `:hover` and `:active`

e.g. `.aButton:active{ /* styles */ }`

Comment: Thanks for the help but the !important in my CSS should override those